# combining UNPIVOT and a SUM in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to UNPIVOT some columns of data which I've managed to do with no problem, the issue I have is that I need to do a calculation between columns before unpivotting the data - is this possible? I've tried to do a SUM but I keep getting a "missing comma" error so I suspect something is not right.

This is the syntax I am using:

```
select 
unpvt.YY,
substr(unpvt.ACCT,1,6) CC,
substr(unpvt.ACCT,7,5) Nom,
substr(unpvt.ACCT,12,6) Det,
substr(unpvt.ACCT,18,4) Fund,
substr(unpvt.period,9,2) Period,
unpvt.Value
from TEBBALS b
INNER JOIN (select CMPY,SYSREF,ACCT FROM TEBACCT WHERE CMPY = 'RC' and PATH = '0') 
d  on b.CMPY = d.CMPY and b.SYSREF = d.SYSREF
unpivot(value for period in 
(
OPEN_BAL,
PER_BAL_01, 
PER_BAL_02, 
PER_BAL_03,
PER_BAL_04, 
PER_BAL_05, 
PER_BAL_06,
PER_BAL_07,
PER_BAL_08,
PER_BAL_09,
PER_BAL_10,
PER_BAL_11,
PER_BAL_12 ) )unpvt
WHERE YY = '2013'
```

The PER_BAL* fields contain balances at the end of a period and I need it to show the movement between periods, so I need to do a calculation between periods, so `(PER_BAL_01 - OPEN_BAL), (PER_BAL_02 - PER_BAL_01)` etc.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm a newbie to SQL so having to teach myself! I am using ODBC to connect to an Oracle server through Cognos TM1 however I am testing all scripts using Oracle SQL Developer first as that is slightly more helpful at diagnosing issues.

Comment: Could you add an example illustrating what you would like to achieve?